# Unable to install or update to fastqc v0.11.9

Tags: updates

I want to use the latest version of fastqc for RNA-seq data analysis. I used

```
sudo apt install fastqc
```

and got FastQC v0.11.5. However, I want to use the latest version FastQC v0.11.9 as this previous version is ignoring tiles>500. I tried to install and unzip the folder from download link from https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastqc/

Still Ubuntu pulls up the older version only. I am using  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on Windows 10. Can you please suggest a command to install FastQC v0.11.9 and run the analysis using latest version? Thanks.

Comment: First, remove the Ubuntu repository version with `apt purge fastqc`. Then install the latest version from the source link.

Comment: @zx485 Thanks. I get following error when I ran this command: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: @zx485 I successfully removed the current version by running the command as root. As described on the source link, I downloaded and unzipped the latest FastQC version. When I checked for the current version, it gives:     `Command 'fastqc' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install fastqc`        which installs the previous version. If I try `apt install fastqc/0.11.9`  it says `E: Release '0.11.9' for 'fastqc' was not found' but it is available to download from the source link. Any suggestion?

Comment: After unzipping the latest version, you have to move it to the right location. Unfortunately I do not know where this may be. But you can always run it from the unzipped directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the older version of fastqc using `apt purge fastqc`, I downloaded the latest version folder and extracted the files in my Users folder. To make it recognizable by Ubuntu, I set the FastQC directory in my PATH using

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/shivani/fastqc_v0.11.9/FastQC
```

and checked the version by

```
fastqc --version
```

The only downside is that every time I launch Ubuntu, I have to set FastQC in PATH to make it accessible.